# cPanel Cron Job to run git reset

Tags: git, cron, cpanel, reset

I'm using the Cron Job section of the cPanel and I am attempting to run a git reset every half hour. I typed something like this into the command field

/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/website.com/ && git reset --hard 932591389576b76215ce9dbb8fdea787115891ef

932591389576b76215ce9dbb8fdea787115891ef being the last commit I made

I set the 30-minute interval and hit the Add New Cron Job button but then

I keep getting this error in a cPanel email and it states

"fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

The path I have given is for certain a git repository as I use it daily, so this message is confusing to me.

Any help in figuring out how to get this command to run would pretty much save my life

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cd to the directory first.

30 * * * * cd /usr/local/bin/php/home/username/public_html/website.com/ && git reset --hard

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, but unfortunately that did not work. The cPanel messages is now alerting that this is not a directory.

Comment: Okay it kinda of did. The CD was the part you were missing, but the directory of your git repo was wrong. Glad you resolved it.

Comment: Yes, thank you. You had it exactly right, it was the path that was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working here is the command

30 * * * * cd /home/username/public_html/website.com/ && git reset --hard etc...

The solution was to omit /usr/local/bin/php from the path